# How to increase accuracy of floating point second derivative calculation?

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I've written a simple program to calculate the first and second derivative of a function, using function pointers. My program computes the correct answers (more or less), but for some functions, the accuracy is less than I would like.

This is the function I am differentiating:

```
float f1(float x) {
    return (x * x);
}
```

These are the derivative functions, using the central finite difference method:

```
// Function for calculating the first derivative.

float first_dx(float (*fx)(float), float x) {
    float h = 0.001;
    float dfdx;

    dfdx = (fx(x + h) - fx(x - h)) / (2 * h);
    return dfdx;
}

// Function for calculating the second derivative.

float second_dx(float (*fx)(float), float x) {
    float h = 0.001;
    float d2fdx2;

    d2fdx2 = (fx(x - h) - 2 * fx(x) + fx(x + h)) / (h * h);
    return d2fdx2;
}
```

Main function:

```
int main() {
    pc.baud(9600);
    float x = 2.0;

    pc.printf("**** Function Pointers ****\r\n");
    pc.printf("Value of f(%f): %f\r\n", x, f1(x));
    pc.printf("First derivative: %f\r\n", first_dx(f1, x));
    pc.printf("Second derivative: %f\r\n\r\n", second_dx(f1, x));
}
```

This is the output from the program:

```
**** Function Pointers ****
Value of f(2.000000): 4.000000
First derivative: 3.999948
Second derivative: 1.430511
```

I'm happy with the accuracy of the first derivative, but I believe the second derivative is too far off (it should be equal to ~2.0).

I have a basic understanding of how floating point numbers are represented and why they are sometimes inaccurate, but how can I make this second derivative result more accurate? Could I be using something better than the central finite difference method, or is there a way I can get better results with the current method?

Comment: well to increase accuracy I would suggest using `double` instead of `float`.

Comment: Or maybe even `long double`?

Comment: Ah perfect! How did I not think of this before? The output is now `4.000000` and `2.000000` for first and second derivatives, respectively. For whatever reason, I thought double and float were the same size.

Comment: @StackDanny why don't you make it an answer?

Comment: You may want to change the precision of your print statements, something with more decimal places.  Remember that the printed precision may be different than the internal precision (usually the internal precision is more accurate).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks for the suggestion, I just printed 10 decimal places and the second derivative is accurate to 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go analytical. ;-) probably not an option given "with the current
  method".
- Use double instead of float.
- Vary the epsilon (*h*), and combine the results in some way. For example you could try 0.00001, 0.000001, 0.0000001 and average them. In fact, you'd want the result with the smallest *h* that doesn't overflow/underflow. But it's not clear how to detect overflow and underflow.

Comment: When I reduce h, the second derivative becomes less accurate. For example, `h = 10^-4` --> `2.0000000767`, `h = 10^-5` --> `2.0000001655` and `h = 10^-6` --> `2.0010659796`. I would have thought it should become more accurate. Any idea on why this could be?

Comment: Varying `h` as this answer suggests is not a good idea. `h` must be small enough that the functions behavior is nearly linear over the probed interval but large enough that the change in function value is many ULP (landing around the middle of the significand might be good). The sample values given in this answer all fail the latter criterion.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I understand the first point about the function being approximately linear over the interval `x - h` to `x + h`. But could you please explain the second point? I know the ULP is the Unit in the Last Place and the significand is usually the mantissa of some number. But how do they tie in with this?

Comment: @AkThao: Let’s use decimal for illustration and suppose we have a 7-digit decimal format. Consider examining the derivative of f(x)=x² at 2.345. With h=.001, we have f(2.345+.001)=5.503716 and f(2.345) = 5.499025, so the derivative is estimated as (5.503716-5.499025)/.001 = 4.691. With h=.00001, with have f(2.345+.00001)=5.499072, so the derivative is estimated as (5.499072-5.499025)/.00001 = 4.7. Because we only have seven digits and the function changed only in the last two, we have only two in the derivative.

Comment: So, if h is too small, the function cannot change by enough in the digits we have available in the floating-point format. And this is worse for the second derivative. h must be large enough that the changes in the function are at least as many significant digits as we want there to be in the derivative.

Answer (score 3):

The accuracy can be increased by choosing a type which has more precision. `float` is currently defined as an IEEE-754 32-bit number, giving you a precision of ~`7.225` decimal places.

What you want is the 64-bit counterpart: **`double`** with ~`15.955` decimal places accuracy.

---

That should be sufficient for your calculation, however worth mentioning is [boosts implementation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/float128.html) which offers a quadruple-precision floating point number (128-bit).

Finally [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/) offers types with an arbitrary number of decimal places for precision.